# Meteor can't access profile picture

Tags: facebook, node.js, authentication, meteor, webstorm

I'm new to meteor and I'm trying to get the currently loggedin user's picture.

I tried many ways but this one feels like it should work :

This is on the index's js :

```
Template.user_loggedout.events({
"click #login" : function(e, t){
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
    })
   }
})
```

So it basically just logs in with facebook. The authentication is successful up to that point. 
Now in on the server's side, I tried many approach to get the picture when creating the user but this one seemed the cleanest and easiest :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
if (options.profile) {
    options.profile.picture = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large";
    user.profile = options.profile;
}
return user;
});
```

I also tried it with google (with fully implemented google login):

```
user.profile.profile_picture = user.services.google.picture;
```

Now in my view, I simply call it this way :

```
<img src="currentUser.profile.picture"
```

The thing is no matter which way I try, I calways get this broken link image :

[image]

I'm sure I'm an obvious step away to pulling this off but I really can't figure out what is wrong with my calls. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Only guessing because I haven't actually used meteor, but doesn't it use some kind of a templating engine that'll require you to wrap the variable `{{currentUser.profile.picture}}` before plugging into html?

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose the helpers inside double flower brackets {{helper}}. Otherwise it will consider it as a plain text.

`<img scr="{{currentUser.profile.picture}}" alt="{{currentUser.username}}">`

Comment: Yes, it is under brackets. I typed it it instead of copy paste and forgot to put the brackets

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `if(options.profile)` where you end up with

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  options.profile.picture = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large";
  user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```

And then in your template

```
{{#if currentUser}}
  <img scr="{{currentUser.profile.picture}}" alt="{{currentUser.username}}">
{{/if}}
```